# VUE Props still undefined how to fix it?

Tags: vue.js, vue-props

`productPage`

```html
<template>
  <div id="products" class="products">
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="text-center p-5">熱銷商品</h1>
      <div class="row">
        <div v-for="product in products" class="col-md-3">
          <div class="card product-item">
            <swiper :pagination="true" :modules="modules" class="mySwiper">
              <swiper-slide v-for="image in product.data().images">
                <img :src="image" class="card-img-top" alt="..." />
              </swiper-slide>
            </swiper>
            <div class="card-body">
              <div
                class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-between text-center"
              >
                <h5 class="card-title">{{ product.data().name }}</h5>
                <h5 class="card-priceS">
                  {{ currency(product.data().price) }}$
                </h5>
                <p>{{ product.data().description }}</p>
              </div>
              <add-to-cart
                :name="product.data().name"
                :price="product.data().price"
                :product-id="product.id"
                :product-image="getImage(product.data().images)"
              >
              </add-to-cart>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Produtspage',
  components: {
    Navbar,
    Login,
    Swiper,
    SwiperSlide,
  },
  props: {
    msg: String,
  },
  setup() {
    return {
      modules: [Pagination],
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      products: [],
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.readData()
  },
  methods: {
    currency,
    async readData() {
      const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, 'products'))
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        this.products.push(doc)
        console.log(doc.id, ' => ', doc.data())
        console.log(doc.data())
      })
    },
    getImage(images) {
      console.log(images)

      return images
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

`addtocart` component

```html
<template>
  <div class="add-to-cart">
    <button class="btn btn-success fs-6" @click="addToCart">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-cart-plus mx-1"></i>加到購物車
    </button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'AddToCart',
  props: {
    name: String,
    price: String,
    productId: String,
    image: String,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      item: {
        productName: this.name,
        productPrice: this.price,
        product_id: this.productId,
        product_image: this.image,
        // productQuantity: 1,
      },
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

I checked the Vue Devtools, only image no props success, other data does have correct props, the image prop is still `undefined`, the image data is url and when I `console.log(images)`, the data is shown, but props are still `undefined`.

I use firestore for the project, did I do anything wrong here?

Comment: I've formatted your question a bit. More readable now.

Comment: In your `addtocart` component do not copy props into state (`productName: this.name`) as this is one time operation - when prop value changes in the future (for example because some async loading of image), `data` will stay the same. Don't do that. Use prop values directly

Answer (score 1):

#### you are using the wrong name for the binded attribute that dosnt match the prop name :

##### you are using `:product-image`  in  `productPage`

```
<add-to-cart
      :name="product.data().name"
      :price="product.data().price"
      :product-id="product.id"
      :product-image="getImage(product.data().images)"
   >
```

##### so you have to match it with `productImage` instead of <strike>`product-image`</strike> as a prop name in the `addtocart` component

```
props: {
    name: String,
    price: String,
    productId: String,
    productImage: String, // appropriate prop name
  },
```

Comment: Thanks,I found the problem before your answer, but thank you !

Comment: I don't think this is a problem - camelCase and kebab-cased names (for props) [are equivalent in Vue](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics.html#case-insensitivity) due to browser (HTML) limitation - `product-image` is indeed the same as `productImage`

Comment: @MichalLevý i agreee but he didnt write it in kabeb nor in camel , he just wrote image ,
plus in some cases kebab-cases wont work for you ig they work perfectly in sfc's

Comment: @AlbertHsu will you accept my answer so its verified for others ?

Comment: Thanks, I am a rookie , thanks for answer my question